# In a stacked bar plot,How do u plot bars of different categories of a variable (vertically) where every bar starts from x-axis?

Tags: r, excel, worksheet

[image: http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=stacked+bar+chart&view=detailv2&id=CD8EFAE719BFA5FCA1AB1EA6DAA22363E76EAD13&selectedindex=1&ccid=lTsHf2uz&simid=608041385567914091&thid=OIP.M953b077f6bb366647d008eda5ec12aa7H0&mode=overlay&first=1]

In the above picture,
In match 9 team A scores 400 ( on score axis : 0-400), team B scores 90 (on score axis : 400-490) , team C scores 410 (490-900)

What should I do to get a bar diagram where I have all three teams scores bars  starting from x axis for every match? (Bars of lower frequencies should be visible without being superimposed by high frequency ones)

like team A scores 400 ( on score axis : 0-400), team B scores 90 (on score axis : 0-90) , team C scores 410 (0-410)

Solution in R or excel is required

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: reproducible code [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example]

Comment: Intially I had a stacked bar plot.I tried for the one I asked but couldn't figure out a method.I am very new to R and excel.

Comment: Are you asking how to produce a ggplot bar plot this is dodged, not stacked?  Search here for questions on that and offer some code in your question above.  Also, use dput() to provide us with your data set.

Answer (score 0):

The best visualization solution for this lies in rCharts package

library(rCharts)

n1 <- nPlot(score ~ Match, group = "Team", data = player, type = "multiBarChart")
n1

## If you want to publish on github, you can also do

n1$publish("Player", host = 'gist')

## If you want to save as html

n1$save("Player.html")